# Unable to start OHS component

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, httpserver, oracle-http-server, nodemanager

Middleware: Oracle HTTP Server(OHS)
Version: 12.2.1.3
Configured Oracle HTTP Server(OHS) in standalone mode. Node manager is running perfectly. While starting "./startComponent.sh ohs1" i am getting the below error,

"""
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
Error: Error occurred while performing nmConnect : Cannot connect to Node Manager. : Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? 
"""

The solution found in internet is to changing the SecureListener to false in Nodemanager properties file.

When i did that i got the below error,

"""
weblogic.nodemanager.NMConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused). Could not connect to NodeManager. Check that it is running at localhost/XXX.0.X.X:XXXX.
Error: Error occurred while performing nmConnect : Cannot connect to Node Manager. : Connection refused (Connection refused). Could not connect to NodeManager. Check that it is running at localhost/XXX.0.X.X:XXXX. 
"""
And the solution for this is Setting the SecureListener to true in node manager properties file.
I am confused. Can someone help in resolving these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed Oracle Access Manager(OAM) and OHS on same machine, but installed OHS in Standalone mode in different folder. After that, uninstalled OHS and Installed OHS in the same folder where i installed OAM, It worked.